# How do I access my callback function data in multer?

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to access my callback information. I am not super good an understanding where exactly the callback information is going in general. Everything in the multer destination and file options are working well. I want to be able to access either the data I just sent to it, or the modified data I sent in the callback functions of them. What I have is below, and what I want is commented below in the post function...

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb){
    var dir0 = __dirname + '/recordings/'+file.originalname.split('!')[1];
    var dir1 = dir0 +"/"+file.originalname.split('!')[0];
    fs.existsSync(dir0) || fs.mkdirSync(dir0);
    fs.existsSync(dir1) || fs.mkdirSync(dir1);
    
    //first we do some housekeeping. place two files into the given folder to open the video and text
    if(!fs.existsSync(dir1+'/index.php'))
    {
          fs.copyFile(__dirname + '/recordings/index.php', dir1+'/index.php', function(err) {
          if (err) {
            throw err
          } else {
            //console.log("Successfully copied and moved the file!")
          }
        })
        fs.copyFile(__dirname + '/recordings/read.php', dir1+'/read.php', function(err) {
          if (err) {
            throw err
          } else {
            //console.log("Successfully copied and moved the file!")
          }
        })
    }
    
        // File upload will be placed in upload folder under public after successful upload
      cb(null, dir1+"/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb){
    
    if(file.fieldname==='data')
    {
        // Set the name of the file to its original name, or add other characters to distinguish the same file, such as file. originalname + new Date (). getTime (); use time to distinguish
        cb(null, file.originalname.split('!')[0]+'.webm')
    }
    if(file.fieldname==='txt')
    {
        // Set the name of the file to its original name, or add other characters to distinguish the same file, such as file. originalname + new Date (). getTime (); use time to distinguish
        cb(null, file.originalname.split('!')[0]+'.txt')
    }
  }
});
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});



//app post to process video/text data at the end of a session
app.post('/recorded', upload.fields([{
           name: 'data'
         }, {
           name: 'txt'
         }]), async function(req,res){
       
       //req or res. something? give me the information in data/text that I sent just above, or the second item in any of the cb functions above (I want to do more with this after it's processed through file creation)
       //not sure how to access any of this data (file or cb)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that have this question in the future, it's hard for anyone to know up front (Nobody knows all programming like the back of their hand, and especially not lower level stuff). The key is just to console.log(req). From doing that, I found out what my desired directory is by getting out sublime text, installing brackethighlighter, and trying to go further into the json. This is what I ended up with for my desired destination location:

`console.log(res.req.files.data[0].destination);`